# Using Javascript UI controls Vs Server-side Controls

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controls

While looking for a 3rd party web UI controls library, I need to know whether I should go for a script based solution like ExtJS,DHTMLX, YUI, etc or a server side one like telerik or DevExpress? Tell me with these areas in view:

1- control
2- performance
3- programmatic manipulation
4- ease of development
5- learning curve

Answer (score 0):

in performance i think java-script Based are faster and more user-friendly because of the ability to dynamically change during the run time 
while server base GUI's are static like a stone 
i don't know in other views

Comment: Ok. Sounds correct. Anybody else? Especially when we are building an MVC 3 web app where server-side controls are not presumably 1st class citizens.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you need.

For MVC3 Web apps I would recommend client side libraries.
jQuery UI is small and fast, very popular so community is strong. 
Downside is it has relatively small number of widgets.

If you need greater number of widgets then use something as ExtJS or YUI but that comes with a price of size and performance.

I think best approach is to check out websites of jQuery UI and YUI and see which widgets do you really need.
If jQuery UI satisfies you, then go for jQuery UI.